# Why does my code return null?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to extend an NSMutableArray with queue like selectors one such is

```
- (id)dequeue {
    id obj = nil;
    if ([self count] > 0) {
        id obj = [self objectAtIndex:0];
        if (obj != nil) {
            [self removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Problem is that I have ARC enabled and the data that `obj` points at is released at `removeObjectAtIndex:` so `dequeue` always returns null.

What's an elegant way to work around this or is my approach completely wrong?

*edit*
This was caused by a typo and has nothing to do with ARC.

Comment: Also, no need to test `obj != nil` an object returned from `objectAtIndex:` can never be `nil` (unless you have screwed up the internal data structure of your array).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo error.

Comment: And maybe also the question text - so people don't get confused by the ARC reference, people seem to blame ARC for all sorts of things, so no need to lead them further astray :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a simple scope issue. The internal `obj` variable is not the same as the one you are returning. Change your code to this and it should work

```
- (id)dequeue {
    id obj = nil;
    if ([self count] > 0) {
        obj = [self objectAtIndex:0]; // removed "id" on this line since it created a new variable that and didn't assign to the one you were returning.
        if (obj != nil) {
            [self removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: DOH! Thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO let's me.

Comment: I actually thought the compiler would emit a warning in cases like this, but I must have been working with more hand-holding compilers when I got that impression.

Comment: @Monolo As far as I know it would only warn if the the outer `obj` was an instance variable. What really surprised me was that the analyser didn't find this when I tried that code just now.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Right, that's it. I mixed the two cases up.